# When to build the DB structure when testing with arquilian?

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

I am starting with integration tests and Arquilian. I am very happy with the tool.
I have almost everything set, except for one thing:

My database structure is of course stable during  the whole test suite, so, in order to reduce the tiem it takes for the test to run, I would like to build the database as least often as possible and have each test fill the database, work on it and clean it.

I imagine that  building the database on the beginning of the test suite and let all the tests fill/erase the database may be a little risky: if one test doesn't clean well, I may get non-reproducible tests.

But maybe building it at every test class is a nice approach, in case of a problematic test, it would be easier to spot, since the scope is smaller.

I tried to do that using the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass, but these are executed on the client and are also static, so I have no resource ready to be used to connect to the database.

Is my approach of creating the DB structure before each test correct? Which phase of arquilian's lifecycle that can be used to build the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do it on your own, at least if you're using JPA 2.1 in your project. Consider the following test class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() throws Exception {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addAsResource("META-INF/init-schema.sql")  // create table ...
            .addAsResource("META-INF/testdata.sql")  // insert into ...
            .addAsResource("META-INF/drop-schema.sql") // drop table ...
            .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
            // and maybe more ...
    }

}
```

The `createDeployment()` method is called to create the WAR file, that's to be deployed to your app server.

Your `persistence.xml` should reference those SQL scripts:

```
[...]
<persistence-unit [...]>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/init-schema.sql" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/drop-schema.sql" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/testdata.sql" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This way the database is set up automatically when the test-WAR is being deployed. Make sure the SQL files are in the "META-INF" folder (if you're using Maven it's in "src/test/resources/META-INF").

If you want to control the order in which your test methods are being executed, you can use the `@InSequence` annotation, for example:

```
public class MyTest {
    [...]

    private @Inject EntityManager entityManager

    @Test @InSequence(0)
    public void shouldHaveFoo() {
        Foo foo = entityManager.find(Foo.class, Long.valueOf(1));
        assertNotNull(foo);
    }

    @Test @InSequence(1)
    public void shouldHaveBar() {
        Bar bar = entityManager.find(Bar.class, Long.valueOf(99));
        assertNotNull(bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great news! I will try ASAP (probably Monday) and let you know! thanks!

Comment: The script I want to use in the test is the one that is used to deploy in the database, and it uses $$ as delimiter. I got the error message: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [DELIMITER $$]

Comment: It's probably because of line breaks. Have a look at my [SqlAsset class](https://gist.github.com/jabu10245/80351433704e79d4fa2e). It merges multiple files into one SQL file and handles $$ delimiters as well. Add this asset to the WAR with `addAsResource(sqlAsset, "testdata.sql")`

Answer (score 1):

Use Transaction extension for Arqullian which works pretty good (http://arquillian.org/modules/transaction-extension/). Data which you create in transaction are removed after testing finishes.

Only problem is that data which are at DB can impact you testing. The solution is test against empty DB. It can be embedded, real or approach which is described above. But the extension manages all transaction management properly and you do not have to care about nothing.